# shortcut to the desktop in the menubar

Tags: shortcuts

how do I get a shortcut to my desktop in the menubar?
i.e. a clickable item that minimizes (or the like) all windows that are currently open.

thanks

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I usually keep an extra workspace with no launched apps in it to access the desktop, where Ctrl+Alt+Right|Left Arrow switches workspaces, so I no longer need such a function.

Answer (score 1):

For unity, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is the shortcut that does the trick. Not clickable, but memorable.

(Super stands for Windows logo key on most PCs)

Comment: What plugin is responsible for this?

Comment: ccsm, general, general options, key bindings, show desktop.

Comment: lol I found it before you answered :P! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no "Show desktop" applet / icon for the Unity panel in Ubuntu 11.04 and while you can use Super + D to toggle Show Desktop, many are used to using an icon for this. So here's how to get such an icon on your Unity panel.

I. Install wmctrl:

> sudo apt-get install wmctrl

II. Download the script and .desktop file, extract it and place the "showdesktop" script in the /usr/local/bin folder using the commands below

> cd
>
> wget http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/showdesktop.tar.gz
>
> tar -xvf showdesktop.tar.gz && rm showdesktop.tar.gz
>
> sudo mv showdesktop /usr/local/bin/

III. Now you should see a file called "showdesktop.desktop" in your home folder - you can move it wherever you want (or leave it there) and then simply drag it to the Unity launcher and you'll have a "Show desktop" icon.

[image: Show Desktop Icon]

For More Visit
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/show-desktop-icon-for-ubuntu-unity.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes Roland.. Will surely do.. I have a question, Won't the guy on the website who wrote that How-To think that I stole his post and put it here..

Comment: Nope :)! It will be an honour to him, trust me.